# Looking for better way to get the fiscal year out of the time stamp in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to let the fiscal year out of the "RequestDate" column following data.

I have used following code which works but looking for better way to do this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as datetime

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

df['CalendarYear'] = df['RequestDate'].dt.year
df['Month'] = df.RequestDate.dt.month
c = pd.to_numeric(df['CalendarYear'])
df['RequestFY'] = np.where(df['Month'] >= 10, c+1, c)
df.drop(['Month', 'CalendarYear'], axis=1, inplace=True)


Before: 
Index   RequestDate     
 0        2019-05-01     
 1        2018-08-02       
 2        2016-01-01       
 3        2015-03-01       
 4        2005-02-01    
 5        2005-10-01

 After:
Index   RequestDate         RequestFY
 0        2019-05-01        2019
 1        2018-08-02        2018
 2        2016-01-01        2016
 3        2015-03-01        2015
 4        2005-02-01        2005
 5        2005-10-01        2006
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dt.qyear` on `Quarter`:

```
df['RequestFY'] = df.RequestDate.dt.to_period('Q-SEP').dt.qyear
```

Output:

```
   Index RequestDate  RequestFY
0      0  2019-05-01       2019
1      1  2018-08-02       2018
2      2  2016-01-01       2016
3      3  2015-03-01       2015
4      4  2005-02-01       2005
5      5  2005-10-01       2006
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has a `qyear` [functionality](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Period.qyear.html) for that very thing.

Answer (score 0):

You didnt specify when the fiscal year begins. Say it begins `July 1st` and runs to `June 3oth`, please try;

```
 df['RequestFY']= pd.to_datetime(df['RequestDate']).apply(pd.Period, freq='A-JUL')#Fiscal year running from July to June

Index   RequestDate RequestFY
0   0   2019-05-01  2019
1   1   2018-08-02  2019
2   2   2016-01-01  2016
3   3   2015-03-01  2015
4   4   2005-02-01  2005
5   5   2005-10-01  2006
```